# How to override alchemy_cms javascript file in gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree, alchemy-cms

I am trying to create a gem that requires alchemy_cms. I need to change the alchemy.js file because it is requiring things multiple times with my spree gem. I attempted to put the new js file in the vendor assets, but that didn't override it. Any ideas?